Anchor links between pages don't scroll in Next.js
In my nextjs project, I have a navigation menu in the header, which has links such as /#apartments, /#reviews and /#contact-us. They all point to the landing page at / and have different hashes to scroll to certain sections within that page.
This works great if you click on one of the links while you're on the same page as the one it points to. However, if you go to a different page and click on one of the links, the page loads, but fails to scroll to the desired section.
I also noticed that it does successfully scroll if the page the link is pointing to has already been visited before, so it's cached.
Maybe this is happening because I have a loading.tsx file, so when the user clicks on the anchor link, it first shows them the loading page and once the page finishes loading, the browser doesn't know it needs to scroll because it already tried to when the page was loading?
I came up with a component, which I put in the root layout.tsx file to make sure it's on every page. It detects a pathname change, checks if the current url has a hash, and if so, scrolls to it after 500ms:
"use client";

import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function InterPageScroller() {
  const pathname = usePathname();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { hash } = location;
    if (!hash) return;

    setTimeout(() => {
      const elem = document.querySelector(hash);
      if (elem) elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }, 500);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}

The obvious problem here is that if I don't defer the scrolling (the 500ms setTimeout), it won't do anything because the useEffect triggers when the pathname changes, which happens before the page loads, so I need to wait for it to load first. And hard-coding the timeout delay is very bad, because depending on the user's internet speed, the loading can take much longer than 500ms, so the setTimeout callback will be run before the page loads and nothing will happen. I haven't found a way to detect when the page fully loads in nextjs. addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", cb) doesn't work.
How can I make anchor links work between pages in nextjs? Or if that's not possible, how can I detect when the page loads to manually scroll to a particular section by using something like element.scrollIntoView()?
Edit
Here's the code for the anchor links:
type NavLinkType = {
  href: string;
  label: string;
  icon?: ReactElement;
};

const HEADER_NAV_LINKS: NavLinkType[] = [
  { href: "/#apartments", label: "Apartments", icon: <HomeIcon /> },
  { href: "/#reviews", label: "Reviews", icon: <StarIcon /> },
  { href: "/#contact-us", label: "Contact us", icon: <PhoneIcon /> },
] as const;

const HEADER_NAV_ITEMS = HEADER_NAV_LINKS.map(({ href, label }) => {
  return (
    <li key={label}>
      <Link href={href} className="hover:underline">
        {label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
});

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <nav className="hidden sm:block">
      <ul className="flex gap-6">{HEADER_NAV_ITEMS}</ul>
    </nav>
  );
}


Can you share code for your anchor links?

Sure, just edited the question

I used ResizeObserver to detect if body's height is changed, then scroll to the hash.
Remember to unobserve when resize window so it won't trigger again.
const App = () => {
  const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => {
    const { hash } = window.location
    const elem = hash.length > 0 && document.querySelector(decodeURI(hash));
    elem && elem.scrollInToView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", () => observer.unobserve(document.body));
    observer.observe(document.body);
    return () => observer.unobserve(document.body);
  }, []);
  return <>...</>
}

